# How to request AWS SES production access for Android app with no website URL?

Tags: amazon-ses

I need AWS SES production access for my android app to send `invite` emails to new users.
The console is asking for a `website url`. Since it is a `react native android app` & i do not have a website for my app. What should i do ?

[image: Console Screenshot]

Comment: You don't have *any* website describing what your app is doing?

Comment: yes for now i do not have, since i never thought it is mandatory for a hobby project

Comment: Well, it's not mandatory for a hobby project, you are right. But you are about to use services from a very  professional environment.